# WriteFIle freezes

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

My program freezes on the next string, when it runs from the remote directory.

```
::WriteFile(dst, ::LockResource(resource_data), resource_size, &written_size, NULL);
```

All arguments are right and output file is located in the %TEMP%.
It looks like security policies denies to write to the file but system doesn't shows any notifications about this.

Same code works good if program runs from the local directory.

I found no information about this case on the MSDN.

UPD: SSCCE.

```
bool ExtractResourceTo(const std::wstring& filename) {
  CHandle file(::CreateFile(filename.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
                            CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == file) {
    LOG("Cannot create file.");
    return false;
  }
  const HINSTANCE instance = _AtlBaseModule.GetModuleINstance();
  HRSRC resource = ::FindResource(instance, kResourceName,
                                  RT_RCDATA);
  if (resource) {
    HGLOBAL resource_data = ::LoadResource(instance, resource);
    DWORD resource_size = ::SizeofResource(instance, resource);
    if (resource_data && resource_size > 0) {
      DWORD written_size;
      LPVOID resource_ptr = ::LockResource(resource_data);
      if (!resource_ptr) {
        LOG("Cannot lock resource.");
        return false;
      }
      ::WriteFile(file, resource_ptr, resource_size,
                  &written_size, NULL);
      if (written_size == resource_size) {
        return true;
      }
      LOG("Write failed.");
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Is `resource_data` a valid `HGLOBAL`? What's the return value of `LockResource`? Is `dst` a valid `HANDLE`? To improve the answer you may want to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exposes the issue.

Comment: Yes, `resource_data`, `dst` and return value of `LockResource()` are valid. I'll provide an SSCCE in a hour or two.

Comment: That is not an SSCCE. It doesn't compile. We cannot run it. We still have no idea what `dst` is. Seems little point in you creating a file if you never use it. We have no proof that `LockResource` succeeds.

Comment: Disable your antivirus and try again.

Comment: Excuse me, please. I forgot to rename `dst` to the `file` this code was copied from the three different functions.

Comment: There is no antivirus on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is ''optimization'' of windows. System starts process and doesn't loads resources immediately. When `WriteFile` trying to access resource, system pauses the thread and reads given resource into the memory, but executable file is on the remote machine and downloading of resource takes really long time, because my resource has near 180MiB.

Thanks to everybody, who tried to resolve my problem.

Comment: This is called demand paging and it is standard on all modern operating systems.